# Choosing a Project

Tags: telecommunication

Sorry if there’s any spelling mistake... I don't know if this is the proper place to ask, but I guess if it isn't, I'll get notified. Anyway, if it isn't, I apologize.

I’m a telecommunications engineering student at the Dominican Republic on my last year and I have to choose a grad project.

I’d like to ask for some recommendations because I’ve tried several ideas and all of them had been rejected. Here are some of the ideas I’ve thought :

-Linked Checkers: Two checker boards with it’s pieces and if I move a piece in one of them, the same piece on the other board will move automatically. It was rejected because it had a lot to do with electronics and programming, but not telecommunications or networking.

-Medical Shared Database: A shared database in several hospitals so that people could be added in one visit and after going to another hospital and using a fingerprint reader, the doctors on that second hospital can access to all data related to that person, and add new data to it. It was rejected because something like that has already been done at my university.

-Smart Bookshelf: a book shelf capable of knowing all the books there and if someone specific book is taken from it, it’ll also notify it. It will use RFID passive tags on each book to tell each one apart and a web app where you can see al the books on your shelf, as well as info about each of them because you entered the ISBN upon registering the book. I haven’t proposed it yet, because I am not able to find a relatively cheap RFID reader and/or antenna that will allow to detect tags from at least 1 or 2m.

The budget for the project is 500$ max. I’ve thought about some other Ideas but they’ve promptly been rejected by my teacher, so I’d like to know if you have any suggestions (either other project or solutions for my shelf, even if it doesn’t involve RFID)

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: This is probably better answered on the Academic SE site.

Comment: for telecom, go for transmitting data over light, combine some proper variables into it, and see what you come up with.  People like flashy things with lots of buzz.

Comment: @EricS, I'll try with that, I didn't know it existed.

Comment: @Abel, thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a look

Comment: How about try to help solve this problem? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42460/where-do-i-start-with-learning-how-to-transfer-data-via-rf, As noted you could use cellular. The project will be less than $500.