# Where do I start with learning how to transfer data via RF

Tags: frequency-response, transmission, data, radiation, radio

So I literally have no idea where to start but I know what I want to make.

The goal is to somehow transmit 25mb/s of data across 15km with high penetration. Acceptable for reaching through trees and rocky areas in the mountains.

I would like to focus on lower frequencies like 1.3ghz or 2.4ghz but I know there are limitations to that frequency. I really don't have a clue where to start if someone could point me in a good direction that would be amazing.

I was thinking it would be cool to use 1.3ghz and transmit on multiple channels, then combine them all to get the desired data rate.

Again i'm super noob at this kind of stuff so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: I would take a look are the Lora communication protocol. The frequency is sub gigahertz.

Comment: LORA might be a good solution, I also would suggest looking at Cellular, which might be a better option.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena to be honest the solution would be to transmit live video, with great penetration. I've read LORA is great, but I didn't think it could produce those kind of data rates?

Comment: @Karekin_FPV Your question doesn't state video. You might want to update the body of the question with this critical piece of information. This leave you with cellular as an option.

Comment: If you're a super nob, you need to learn circuit basics before taking this on. You will need it and a lot lot lot more.